# Why is Roku player throwing error "reader pick stream error:bad:invalid or corrupt playlist" when play a Stream using AKAMAI CDN

Tags: cdn, roku, brightscript, akamai, ott

We are using the Akamai CDN HLS stream for one of our OTT apps. This app has two types (Live & VOD) stream URLs. When playing the VOD content the Roku player plays the stream smoothly but when we play Live Stream content, the Roku player throws the error "**reader pick stream error:bad:invalid or corrupt playlist**" When playing this stream on other players like Apple TV, VLC, Exo Player, Android TV and Web Players (JWplayer, HTML5) then steaming is working as expected.

**Also, few Live videos playing on the Roku Player.**

Already, I have checked these points.

1. Checked API calling and endpoints
2. URL formation for player
3. Managed Cookies
4. Checked HTTP protocols like 1.0/1.1/2.0
5. Checked Bitrates 25000 above
6. Matched video codec
7. There is although difference in resolution, But same resolution is working fine in VOD Section.

I am digging last 4 weeks but unfortunately I have not got any solution yet.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Did you tried with Roku stream tester? If stream is not working or you are getting same error then there is some issue with stream itself. If stream is working fine with stream tester, then something is wrong with video player settings.

Comment: @swaran, Thanks for the replied. We have checked on the Roku Stream Tester and getting same error code as well as error message. It means, something went wrong on the  server level (May be some Live Videos are not encoding  properly for the Roku Player compatible)

Comment: that's great. Further you can check whether  video url headers, drm(if applicable) are configured properly. Also you can check video manifest file if there is something suspicious over there. Also you can try to get some info about downloaded video segments before player throws an error. Most likely these things can help to track down the error.

Comment: One other thought is that the Live Video has to be produced with the correctly formatted HLS manifest. The error suggests to me that the M3U8 is not formatted properly for live video. For example, using the #EXT-X-ENDLIST in a live stream is a no-no. Maybe the Roku player is looking for #EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:EVENT? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/example_playlists_for_http_live_streaming